# Adding an entry for a matched $module

Tags: perl

What would be the most efficient way to write the following code in Perl:

```
       my $index = 0;
       foreach ( @spec ) {
          if ( $module =~ m/$_/ ) {
         splice(@spec, $index, 0, $module);
             last;         
          }
          $index++;
       }
```

This works fine but just seems a little wordy. The idea is that where I find a match for $module in the array I add an entry. I want to keep the array in a certain order and sorted.

Answer (score 5):

You want "more efficient wordiness"??? I presume you're not asking for golfing, but for code that's more readable from conciseness.

```
@spec = map { $_ eq $module ? ($_, $_) : $_ } @spec;
```

Comment: Yeah this is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

1. You manually increment the `$index`. Just loop over the indices instead:

   ```
   for my $index (0 .. $#spec) {
     if ($module =~ /$spec[$index]/) {
       splice @spec, $index, 0, $module;
       last;
     }
   }
   ```

   On newer perls (v12+) you can use `each` on arrays:

   ```
   use 5.012;
   while(my ($i, $str) = each @spec) {
      if ($module =~ /$str/) {
        splice @spec, $i, 0, $module;
        keys @spec; # reset the `each` iterator
        last;
      }
   }
   ```
2. If the values in `@spec` are not regexes, but just plain strings, and iff you want to test that `$module` *contains* the string in `$spec[$index]`, then you could use `index` for better efficiency.

   ```
   if (-1 != index $module, $spec[$index]) { ... }
   ```

   This also won't treat characters like `\[]()?+*` as metacharacters any more. This would be similar to `/\Q$spec[$index]\E/` (see `quotemeta` function), but more efficient

   If you actually want to apply the string as a regex, this point is moot.

Comment: Ad. #1: I'd use foreach loop and increment counter manyally just like OP, so it's rather subjective _(although `each` would be my choice if all production code run on >= v5.12)._

Comment: It would probably be safer to reset the iterator before you modify the array.